# time stamp ros_info

Tags: ros, ros-info

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I've been using ROS_INFO instead of printf, and wonder which time is being printed. The time being printed at start is 5.339. I can't imagine this is system time, so what is it and which standard is it in? (seconds, milliseconds).

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/193820/time-stamp-ros_info/) by [hvn](https://answers.ros.org/users/3729/hvn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 72 on 2014-09-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are you using Gazebo and your node with use_sim_time set true?

The ros:Time API wraps the system Time so that in simulation Nodes can use the sim time of the /clock topic as their ros::Time, see http://wiki.ros.org/Clock.  Source of the sim time maybe rosbags or simulators like Gazebo. If your simulation is been active for approx. 5 sec, this time in your ROS_INFO log would be senseful....

Edit:
If you start gazebo it sets the parameter use_sim_time true; you can see it beeing true by command line:

```
rosparam get /use_sim_time
```

Because it is true each node started after gazebo will not use system time as ros time but the simulation time published to clock topic. You can see the clock topic being published with:

```
rostopic echo /clock
```

This means each attempt to retrieve ros::Time in your nodes will result in the simulation time, not system time! Therefore your logs will be stamped with the simulation time!

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2014-09-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hvn](https://answers.ros.org/users/3729/hvn/) on 2014-09-30**:
I am using Gazebo, but not use_sim_time. So what does that mean for me ? In addition: the start time was 5.339 and the end time was 12.54.

**Comment by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) on 2014-09-30**:
Please see the edit

**Comment by [hvn](https://answers.ros.org/users/3729/hvn/) on 2014-09-30**:
Thank you for the edit. Can you tell me in what units the simulation time is (us, ms, s ?)

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2014-09-30**:
Time is in seconds: Standard units are expressed in [REP 103](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0103.html)